# Why are Bounding Coordinates not as expected?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, extents, india

I have a shapefile in GCS_WGS_1984 projection, but the bounding coordinates/Feature extent shows the wrong coordinates in the screenshot below.

[image: Feature of extent of shape file].

I tried to change the projection, by deleting the *.prj file and defining a new projection but it still did not get a good result.

Can anyone explain what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Which part of the world is this? And what other projections could there possibly be in that area? How did you try to change the projection (from what to what?), via the [Project tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000007m000000)?

Also, do you _know_ that the file's coordinates are in WGS 1984, or do you _want_ it to be?

Comment: This is data of Andhra Pradesh(INDIA).Projection is EPSG:4326, UTM :WGS 1984 44N. I changed projection using  project tool from data management only.It can be any projection ..

Comment: Would you be able to use the edit button to include the details you just gave as a comment into a revised Question, please?  You say that the coordinates are wrong but not what coordinate values you were expecting to see.

Comment: Actually Projection of the shapefile is GCS_WGS_1984(decimal degree), therefore Bounding coordinates also to be in decimal degree(lat/long). It giving unit as a degree but the coordinates are not degree decimal(like 09.50 75.12 )

Comment: Your questions and comments have contradictory information, and are hard to understand. Was the data originally in wgs84 lat-long, and you changed the projection by deleting the .prj file? or did you use the project tool in ArcToolbox? Or did you use the 'Define Projection' tool in ArcToolbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EPSG:4326` is **not** the same as `UTM :WGS 1984 44N`.

**EPSG:32644** should be the projection that you want. It is based on the WGS84 ellipsoid, but using projected metres instead of degrees. And that is what your extent data looks like.